# Magento 2 - hide & disable add type product (Simple product ... etc)

Tags: magento2, product, product-type

On Magento 2, and product page, there's a list of product type,

[image: List of type products]

I want to `hide` and `disable` and `block` a user to access an additional type of product,

for example: hide `Configurable product` and `Bundle product` and block the routes of it ( so, you can't add a configurable if you using the URL directly )

Comment: Please check my 2nd answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the class **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product** using di.xml preference as describe below.

Assume you are using a custom module name "**Company_MyModule**"

**step 1:** create **di.xml** under YOUR-MAGENTO-**ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/adminhtml**

File: **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product" type="Company\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Product" />                
</config>
```

**step 2:** Create the class **Product.php** under **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml**

File : **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml/Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product
{
     protected function _getAddProductButtonOptions()
    {
        /* var Array $arrAlowedTypes */     
        $arrAlowedTypesIds = array('simple');
        $splitButtonOptions = [];
        $types = $this->_typeFactory->create()->getTypes();
        uasort(
            $types,
            function ($elementOne, $elementTwo) {
                return ($elementOne['sort_order'] < $elementTwo['sort_order']) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        );

        foreach ($types as $typeId => $type) {
            if(in_array($typeId,$arrAlowedTypesIds)) {              
             $splitButtonOptions[$typeId] = [
                'label' => __($type['label']),
                'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->_getProductCreateUrl($typeId) . "')",
                'default' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::DEFAULT_TYPE == $typeId,
             ];
          }
        }

        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Run DI compile

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

[image]

Comment: It's work perfectly sir, thanks a lot, but if I use URL directly can that work? or redirect me ?

Comment: I am sorry could not understand your question.

Comment: Don't worry sir, I'm a beginner at English, my question is: After hiding the product type and I use URL directly, ex: `catalog/product/new/set/4/type/configurable` that I'm going to get the page or I redirect to catalog product page?

Answer (score 1):

To disable access from direct URL.

You can override the class **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product** using di.xml preference as described below.

Assume you are using a custom module name "**Company_MyModule**"

**step 1:** create **di.xml** under YOUR-MAGENTO-**ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/adminhtml**

File: **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

  <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction" 
    type="Company\My-Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction" />   

</config>
```

**step 2:** Create the class **NewAction.php** under **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/Company/MyModule/Controller/Adminhtml/**

File : **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/Company/MyModule/Controller/Adminhtml/NewAction.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction
{

   public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('set')) {
            return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
        }

         $arrAlowedTypesIds = array('simple');
         $typeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('type');
         if(!in_array($typeId,$arrAlowedTypesIds)) {    
            return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
         }

         return parent::execute();        

    }

}
```

**Step 3:** Run DI compile

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

[image: Product page - Magento 2]

Comment: I try it, but it's doesn't work, if I change the URL with other, (Ex : `product/new/set/4/type/simple` with `product/new/set/4/type/virtual` ) I get the page without any problem, It's doesn't use the new Controller

Comment: Please make sure your overridden controller is working by putting a die() . If the overridden controller not called then it will not work. Also, double check your di.xml.

Comment: I do an `echo` with `die` on the new controller, and I didn't get it ( the page work without any problem ), that I need to add something to `di.xml`? (because your has no information)

Comment: I forget to add preference to di.xml, it's work now sir, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Great!. You are most welcome. Please don't call sir.